# React-native map: MapView with the Animated API is lagging too much in android

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I've just copied the MapView with the Animated API from react-native-map. It works but the performance is too slow in android devices (Samsung). Has anyone experience it? How can it be solved?

Have a look at the video [here](https://youtu.be/EhdbT51R9bo)

P.S I don't need the component on top of the map to move upward so I have deleted the transform Y. Keeping it or not has no effect in performance. The app hangs after sometime.

code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Dimensions,
  Animated,
} from 'react-native';

import {
  ProviderPropType,
  Animated as AnimatedMap,
  AnimatedRegion,
  Marker,
} from 'react-native-maps';
import PanController from './PanController';
import PriceMarker from './AnimatedPriceMarker';

const screen = Dimensions.get('window');

const ASPECT_RATIO = screen.width / screen.height;
const LATITUDE = 37.78825;
const LONGITUDE = -122.4324;
const LATITUDE_DELTA = 0.0922;
const LONGITUDE_DELTA = LATITUDE_DELTA * ASPECT_RATIO;

const ITEM_SPACING = 10;
const ITEM_PREVIEW = 10;
const ITEM_WIDTH = screen.width - (2 * ITEM_SPACING) - (2 * ITEM_PREVIEW);
const SNAP_WIDTH = ITEM_WIDTH + ITEM_SPACING;
const ITEM_PREVIEW_HEIGHT = 150;
const SCALE_END = screen.width / ITEM_WIDTH;
const BREAKPOINT1 = 246;
const BREAKPOINT2 = 350;
const ONE = new Animated.Value(1);

function getMarkerState(panX, panY, scrollY, i) {
  const xLeft = (-SNAP_WIDTH * i) + (SNAP_WIDTH / 2);
  const xRight = (-SNAP_WIDTH * i) - (SNAP_WIDTH / 2);
  const xPos = -SNAP_WIDTH * i;

  const isIndex = panX.interpolate({
    inputRange: [xRight - 1, xRight, xLeft, xLeft + 1],
    outputRange: [0, 1, 1, 0],
    extrapolate: 'clamp',
  });

  const isNotIndex = panX.interpolate({
    inputRange: [xRight - 1, xRight, xLeft, xLeft + 1],
    outputRange: [1, 0, 0, 1],
    extrapolate: 'clamp',
  });

  const center = panX.interpolate({
    inputRange: [xPos - 10, xPos, xPos + 10],
    outputRange: [0, 1, 0],
    extrapolate: 'clamp',
  });

  const selected = panX.interpolate({
    inputRange: [xRight, xPos, xLeft],
    outputRange: [0, 1, 0],
    extrapolate: 'clamp',
  });

  const translateY = Animated.multiply(isIndex, panY);

  const translateX = panX;

  const anim = Animated.multiply(isIndex, scrollY.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, BREAKPOINT1],
    outputRange: [0, 1],
    extrapolate: 'clamp',
  }));

  const scale = Animated.add(ONE, Animated.multiply(isIndex, scrollY.interpolate({
    inputRange: [BREAKPOINT1, BREAKPOINT2],
    outputRange: [0, SCALE_END - 1],
    extrapolate: 'clamp',
  })));

  // [0 => 1]
  let opacity = scrollY.interpolate({
    inputRange: [BREAKPOINT1, BREAKPOINT2],
    outputRange: [0, 1],
    extrapolate: 'clamp',
  });

  // if i === index: [0 => 0]
  // if i !== index: [0 => 1]
  opacity = Animated.multiply(isNotIndex, opacity);


  // if i === index: [1 => 1]
  // if i !== index: [1 => 0]
  opacity = opacity.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [1, 0],
  });

  let markerOpacity = scrollY.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, BREAKPOINT1],
    outputRange: [0, 1],
    extrapolate: 'clamp',
  });

  markerOpacity = Animated.multiply(isNotIndex, markerOpacity).interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [1, 0],
  });

  const markerScale = selected.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [1, 1.2],
  });

  return {
    translateY,
    translateX,
    scale,
    opacity,
    anim,
    center,
    selected,
    markerOpacity,
    markerScale,
  };
}

class AnimatedViews extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const panX = new Animated.Value(0);
    const panY = new Animated.Value(0);

    const scrollY = panY.interpolate({
      inputRange: [-1, 1],
      outputRange: [1, -1],
    });

    const scrollX = panX.interpolate({
      inputRange: [-1, 1],
      outputRange: [1, -1],
    });

    const scale = scrollY.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, BREAKPOINT1],
      outputRange: [1, 1.6],
      extrapolate: 'clamp',
    });

    const translateY = scrollY.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, BREAKPOINT1],
      outputRange: [0, -100],
      extrapolate: 'clamp',
    });

    const markers = [
      {
        id: 0,
        amount: 99,
        coordinate: {
          latitude: 27.6741672,
          longitude: 85.3094676,
        },
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        amount: 199,
        coordinate: {
          latitude: 27.685064,
          longitude: 85.298746,
        },
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        amount: 285,
        coordinate: {
          latitude: 27.6741672,
          longitude:  85.3094676,
        },
      },
    ];

    const animations = markers.map((m, i) =>
      getMarkerState(panX, panY, scrollY, i));

    this.state = {
      panX,
      panY,
      animations,
      index: 0,
      canMoveHorizontal: true,
      scrollY,
      scrollX,
      scale,
      translateY,
      markers,
      region: new AnimatedRegion({
        latitude: LATITUDE,
        longitude: LONGITUDE,
        latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
        longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
      }),
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { region, panX, panY, scrollX, markers } = this.state;

    panX.addListener(this.onPanXChange);
    panY.addListener(this.onPanYChange);

    region.stopAnimation();
    region.timing({
      latitude: scrollX.interpolate({
        inputRange: markers.map((m, i) => i * SNAP_WIDTH),
        outputRange: markers.map(m => m.coordinate.latitude),
      }),
      longitude: scrollX.interpolate({
        inputRange: markers.map((m, i) => i * SNAP_WIDTH),
        outputRange: markers.map(m => m.coordinate.longitude),
      }),
      duration: 0,
    }).start();
  }

  onStartShouldSetPanResponder = (e) => {
    // we only want to move the view if they are starting the gesture on top
    // of the view, so this calculates that and returns true if so. If we return
    // false, the gesture should get passed to the map view appropriately.
    const { panY } = this.state;
    const { pageY } = e.nativeEvent;
    const topOfMainWindow = ITEM_PREVIEW_HEIGHT + panY.__getValue();
    const topOfTap = screen.height - pageY;

    return topOfTap < topOfMainWindow;
  }

  onMoveShouldSetPanResponder = (e) => {
    const { panY } = this.state;
    const { pageY } = e.nativeEvent;
    const topOfMainWindow = ITEM_PREVIEW_HEIGHT + panY.__getValue();
    const topOfTap = screen.height - pageY;

    return topOfTap < topOfMainWindow;
  }

  onPanXChange = ({ value }) => {
    const { index } = this.state;
    const newIndex = Math.floor(((-1 * value) + (SNAP_WIDTH / 2)) / SNAP_WIDTH);
    if (index !== newIndex) {
      this.setState({ index: newIndex });
    }
  }

  onPanYChange = ({ value }) => {
    const { canMoveHorizontal, region, scrollY, scrollX, markers, index } = this.state;
    const shouldBeMovable = Math.abs(value) < 2;
    if (shouldBeMovable !== canMoveHorizontal) {
      this.setState({ canMoveHorizontal: shouldBeMovable });
      if (!shouldBeMovable) {
        const { coordinate } = markers[index];
        region.stopAnimation();
        region.timing({
          latitude: scrollY.interpolate({
            inputRange: [0, BREAKPOINT1],
            outputRange: [
              coordinate.latitude,
              coordinate.latitude - (LATITUDE_DELTA * 0.5 * 0.375),
            ],
            extrapolate: 'clamp',
          }),
          latitudeDelta: scrollY.interpolate({
            inputRange: [0, BREAKPOINT1],
            outputRange: [LATITUDE_DELTA, LATITUDE_DELTA * 0.5],
            extrapolate: 'clamp',
          }),
          longitudeDelta: scrollY.interpolate({
            inputRange: [0, BREAKPOINT1],
            outputRange: [LONGITUDE_DELTA, LONGITUDE_DELTA * 0.5],
            extrapolate: 'clamp',
          }),
          duration: 0,
        }).start();
      } else {
        region.stopAnimation();
        region.timing({
          latitude: scrollX.interpolate({
            inputRange: markers.map((m, i) => i * SNAP_WIDTH),
            outputRange: markers.map(m => m.coordinate.latitude),
          }),
          longitude: scrollX.interpolate({
            inputRange: markers.map((m, i) => i * SNAP_WIDTH),
            outputRange: markers.map(m => m.coordinate.longitude),
          }),
          duration: 0,
        }).start();
      }
    }
  }

  onRegionChange(/* region */) {
    // this.state.region.setValue(region);
  }

  render() {
    const {
      panX,
      panY,
      animations,
      canMoveHorizontal,
      markers,
      region,
    } = this.state;

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <PanController
          style={styles.container}
          vertical
          horizontal={canMoveHorizontal}
          xMode="snap"
          snapSpacingX={SNAP_WIDTH}
          yBounds={[-1 * screen.height, 0]}
          xBounds={[-screen.width * (markers.length - 1), 0]}
          panY={panY}
          panX={panX}
          onStartShouldSetPanResponder={this.onStartShouldSetPanResponder}
          onMoveShouldSetPanResponder={this.onMoveShouldSetPanResponder}
        >
          <AnimatedMap
            provider={this.props.provider}
            style={styles.map}
            region={region}
            onRegionChange={this.onRegionChange}
          >
            {markers.map((marker, i) => {
              const {
                selected,
                markerOpacity,
                markerScale,
              } = animations[i];

              return (
                <Marker
                  key={marker.id}
                  coordinate={marker.coordinate}
                >
                  <PriceMarker
                    style={{
                      opacity: markerOpacity,
                      transform: [
                        { scale: markerScale },
                      ],
                    }}
                    amount={marker.amount}
                    selected={selected}
                  />
                </Marker>
              );
            })}
          </AnimatedMap>
          <View style={styles.itemContainer}>
            {markers.map((marker, i) => {
              const {
                translateX,
                scale,
                opacity,
              } = animations[i];

              return (
                <Animated.View
                  key={marker.id}
                  style={[styles.item, {
                    opacity,
                    transform: [
                      { translateX },
                      { scale },
                    ],
                  }]}
                />
              );
            })}
          </View>
        </PanController>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

AnimatedViews.propTypes = {
  provider: ProviderPropType,
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
  },
  itemContainer: {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    paddingHorizontal: (ITEM_SPACING / 2) + ITEM_PREVIEW,
    position: 'absolute',
    // top: screen.height - ITEM_PREVIEW_HEIGHT - 64,
    paddingTop: screen.height - ITEM_PREVIEW_HEIGHT - 64,
    // paddingTop: !ANDROID ? 0 : screen.height - ITEM_PREVIEW_HEIGHT - 64,
  },
  map: {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
  },
  item: {
    width: ITEM_WIDTH,
    height: screen.height + (2 * ITEM_PREVIEW_HEIGHT),
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    marginHorizontal: ITEM_SPACING / 2,
    overflow: 'hidden',
    borderRadius: 3,
    borderColor: '#000',
  },
});

export default AnimatedViews;
```

Answer (score 4):

I found the issue is related to the Marker component, if you use children or the image prop there will be 100% CPU usage and will drop the UI thread to zero when using google maps. Try and recreate the marker using the icon prop, that will fix the issue.

Change

```jsx
<Marker
  key={marker.id}
  coordinate={marker.coordinate}
>
  <PriceMarker
    style={{
      opacity: markerOpacity,
      transform: [{ scale: markerScale }]}
    }
    amount={marker.amount}
    selected={selected}
  />
</Marker>
```

to

```jsx
<Marker
  key={marker.id}
  coordinate={marker.coordinate}
  icon={PriceMarkerIcon}
/>
```

Comment: I can confirm having children causes 100% CPU usage, using the icon prop is the way to go! Thank you v much for that

Answer (score 1):

Like Mahdi Bashirpour wrote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59716959/react-native-maps-custom-markers-cause-extreme-lag-and-slow-down-on-android?fbclid=IwAR3vzVZAhsesMDqjixMpNlKoXM0L5u_Zqhi8S83N5ElYEz4M3iw4czL9Z4s), you can also disable props `tracksViewChanges={false}` to fix the issue with 100% CPU usage by the Marker component.