# React Native Maps: Custom Markers cause extreme lag and slow down on android

Tags: google-maps, react-native, react-native-maps, react-native-map-clustering

I load up to about 2000 markers on the map.
It works fine for the first few seconds but then slows down sharply. To fix it I need to clear the app data, then it only works for a few seconds and again like before.

```js
const mapMarkers = [
    {id: 1, code: "603778", lat: 35.761791, lng: 51.389438},
    {id: 2, code: "788621", lat: 35.712278, lng: 51.361785},
    {id: 3, code: "129667", lat: 35.674757, lng: 51.485328},
    {id: 4, code: "999646", lat: 35.772885, lng: 51.446735},
    {id: 5, code: "111524", lat: 35.755656, lng: 51.446774},
    //...
];

let markers = mapMarkers.map(marker => {
    return (<Marker
        key={marker.code}
        coordinate={{latitude: marker.lat, longitude: marker.lng}}
        image={require('./images/markers.png')}
        onPress={() => console.log("pressed")}
    />)
});
```

I tested on `emulator` and `physical device` and had problems with both.

tip: I use `react-native-map-clustering` package for marker cluster.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I tried two ways that would improve performance a bit

1. change `key` to `index` (`key={index}`)

```js
mapMarkers.map((marker, index) => {
    return (<Marker
        key={index}
        ...
    />)
 });
```

2. disable props `tracksViewChanges={false}` or add `icon` props instead of `image`

```js
mapMarkers.map((marker, index) => {
    return (<Marker
        key={index}
        tracksViewChanges={false}
        icon={require('./images/markers.png')}
        ...
    />)
});
```

Comment: key with index is bad practice, there is no performance optimization on it, it has drawbacks

Comment: @beqakokhodze Unless you are mutating the list, it doesn't have any bad impact,  however agree with you that it's not going to help in performing better.

Comment: Setting `tracksViewChanges` is the winner, made a huge difference for me

Comment: Is there any way to solve [my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71124554/how-to-optimise-react-native-maps-performance)? tks so much

Comment: tracksViewChanges={false} worked for me. Thanks

Comment: The "tacksViewChanges={false}" was the one for me, especially on android google maps. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

if you use `MapViewDirections` you have to pass props as  optimizeWaypoints=true
the the issue will be gone. and fully re run the program.

```
<MapViewDirections optimizeWaypoints={true}/>
```